# PyCharmのプロジェクトビューにディレクトリを移すには？

Tags: pycharm

Python pycharm初学者です！pycharm について質問です。

Pycharmの左端にあるプロジェクトビューにディレクトリを移すのはどうすれば良いのですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ツールウィンドウバー(※)にある`1.Project`をクリックするとディレクトリが表示されます。
※　ウィンド左端にある長細い矩形です。

プロジェクトが表示される前のツールウィンドウバー

[image: プロジェクトが表示される前のツールウィンドウバー]

`1.Project`をマウスクリックすると、ディレクトリが表示されます。

[image: プロジェクトが表示された後のツールウィンドウバー]